# Upgrade to AGP 4.2.0 ,unable to generate Jacoco code coverage report

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jacoco-plugin

**Jacoco** code coverage was working fine till I upgrade **Android Gradle Plugin** to **4.2.0** , no only app module code coverage getting generated, for modules it is not working.
Any Idea how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem after upgrading to 4.2.1.

It looks like the Jacoco execution data file for **non-instrumented** unit tests has been renamed to 'jacoco.exec', and moved to the module's top-level directory.

In the configuration of my JacocoReport gradle task, this works for me:

```
executionData.from = "${project.projectDir}/jacoco.exec"
```

**NOTE:** The execution data file for **instrumented** tests has not been renamed or moved.

Comment: I haven't noticed this, my jacoco.exec seems to still be in the same location (${buildDir}/jacoco/${variantName}UnitTest.exec). But I am running into the same problem as the OP. Did you have to make any other changes?

Answer (score 5):

Based on amazing Richard [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626100/2910520), if you previously had this setup (which is pretty standard for unit and instrumented tests with Jacoco in Android)

```
executionData.from = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
  "jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec",
  "outputs/code_coverage/${variantName}AndroidTest/connected/**/*.ec"
])
```

You can switch to this equivalent for AGP 4.2.X

```
executionData.from = files([
  "$project.projectDir/jacoco.exec",
  fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
    "outputs/code_coverage/${variantName}AndroidTest/connected/**/*.ec"
  ])
])
```